# Select "youngest" child (target only) under the mouse in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

**tldr:**
**how does one tell a mouse event to only fire for the youngest child under the mouse, and *not* its parent?**

I'm just making a solitaire game to try to better learn OOP.  I have a Card class and a CardHome class.  Each Card contains a CardHome which can hold a card, and so on.  Thus, moving a card will move all the cards contained in it.  The problem is that my mouse event is detecting the parent of all the cards.  So what I think I need is a way to say "run this mouse event only for the youngest child of the target".  Any way to do that?

```
private function pressCard(me:MouseEvent):void{
        var c:Object = me.target as Card;
        // place card in center of container x wise
        c.x = 0;
        // and down 5
        c.y = 5;

        // bring drag container up to front z order
        addChild(c as Card);

        // begin dragging drag container
        c.startDrag(true);

        // hide mouse
        Mouse.hide();

        // add listener to this card for mouse up
        c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCard);
    }

    private function dropCard(me:MouseEvent):void{
        var c:Object = me.target as Card;

        // release drag container
        c.stopDrag();

        // remove mouse up listener from card
        c.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCard);
        Mouse.show();


        // check for colision with a card that has a matching holder
        for (var i:int = 0; i < deckArray.length; i++){
            if (c.hitTestObject(deckArray[i]) && c != deckArray[i]){
                trace("hit",deckArray[i]._containerOwned._occupied,deckArray[i]._flippable);
                if (deckArray[i]._number == c._number + 1 && deckArray[i]._flippable == false && deckArray[i]._suit != c._suit && deckArray[i]._containerOwned._occupied == false){ 
                    c._containedIn.parent._containerOwned._occupied = false;
                    makeFlippable(c._containedIn.parent);
                    deckArray[i]._containerOwned.addChild(c as Card);
                    c._containedIn = c.parent;                      
                    c.x = 0;
                    c.y = 0;
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }

        // add selected card back to home spot
        c._containedIn.addChild(c);
        c.x = 0;
        c.y = 0;
    }

    private function mOver(me:MouseEvent):void{
        trace(me.target._number);
        trace(getHighestZ());
    }

    private function getHighestZ():Card{
        var highestZ:int = 0;
        var c:Card;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < deckArray.length; i++){
            if (deckArray[i].hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY) && deckArray[i].getChildIndex() > highestZ){
                c = deckArray[i];
                highestZ = deckArray[i].getChildIndex();
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

[image]

Each card is a child of a container in the card above it. I want to be able to select a card and drag it (and its children). The problem is that when I click card B, it selects card E. So what I need is to select the youngest child in the mouse event, and NOT its parent. Any way to control that?

I know I can do mouseChildren true or false. That's fine. It has to be set to true for all of the cards so that I can select them independent of their parent card. Do I need to do something with bubbling my event? That's something I've never understood.

Note: I realize there are problems with mouse mouse over function. Fixing that will be trivial and is kind of a placeholder for now.

Comment: Try changing var c:Object = me.target as Card; to var c:Object = me.currentTarget as Card;

Comment: Ooh... I shall!! I saw that in the API today but maybe misunderstood what that was for. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Go to the parent MC and check its `.numChildren`. If it has four children (`[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`) then the youngest should be accessible via `parentMC.getChildAt( parentMC.numChildren-1 );`... just an avenue to explore till someone gives you a full Answer.

Comment: @VC.One  Good thought but I see a problem with this. Card B isn't the youngest child that its parent has, it is just the youngest child that is under the mouse (cards c and d are younger still).

Comment: @VC.One check out my answer if you're interested. Surprisingly complicated but now I finally understand the bubbling phase of events!

Comment: @Seanonymous check out my answer if your curious what worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tldr:**

**use a combination of `useCapture` set to `true` and the `stopPropagation` method. This allows a user to click an element and have the eventHandler *only* called for the target, not any of the elements between the target and the stage!**

So the key here is to access the as3 event flow. When a mouse event gets triggered it propagates from the stage up through all objects that can receive that type of mouse event. In this case, the cards parents. Then it bubbles back down to the stage. So what I needed was to set the capture setting to true which switches the phase in which the event handler is used to the bubbling phase (this causes the first element to actually call the function to be the actual target) and then, instead of letting the event propagate back down to the stage, call the stopPropagation method. Looks something like this:

```
c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver, true);
```

The `true` here says to fire the function on each element on the way *back* to the stage *from* the target. Then during the `mOver` function I do:

```
stopPropagation();
trace(c._Number);
// and any other code to do on this target
```

Which keeps the event from flowing back down through the other cards under the mouse.

Now instead of an output like

```
5
3
9
```

when the mouse is over the 9 card (which is over a 3 which is over 5) I now get simply

```
9
```

and then when I mouse over the 3 I get

```
3
```

So now the mouse is calling a function for the target *only*. Surprisingly non intuitive but allows for some serious flexibility and control!

[from Adobe on Event Flow](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

[image]

[image]